# docker + django : loop + break using forms

Tags: python, django, loops, docker, interrupt

I am using django in a docker container.  I have a page with two buttons: 'Run' and 'Stop'.  When someone presses 'Run' it should start an optimisation process, when you press 'Stop', it should stop.

**views.py**

```
def runGA(request):
  #read from database and initate form
  rundata = RunModel.objects.get(SID=sid)
  runform = RunForm(request.POST or None, instance = rundata)
  form = runform.save(commit=False)           # initiating the form, to allow writing form.stop to db.stop

    if request.method=="POST":

        if request.POST.get("GA")=="Stop":
          form.stop = True

        if request.POST.get("GA")=="Run":
          for iteration in range(cycles):
            *optimise something with iteration*
            rundata = RunModel.objects.get(SID=sid)
            if rundata.stop == True:
              break
          form.stop = False

        form.save()
        return render(request,"runGA.html",{})
```

This works when I don't use the docker container but just run it locally.  This structure allows to interrupt a loop, but it also allows to show an updating figure while running, or to check settings on other pages while running, etc...
(so I need a solution that would work for all those problems as well)

However, if I run this code in the docker container, it seems as though there's a problem with the request.POST.  It executes all the requests **after** the loop is done, and not **during** as it should be.  And this **only** happens when I run this in a docker container.

Any ideas how come?

Thanks!

**Docker version:**

```
    Client:
    Version:      1.11.1
    API version:  1.23
   Go version:   go1.6.2
   Git commit:   5604cbe
   Built:        Wed Apr 27 15:27:26 UTC 2016
   OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

  Server:
   Version:      1.12.0
   API version:  1.24
   Go version:   go1.6.3
   Git commit:   8eab29e
   Built:        Thu Jul 28 23:54:00 2016
   OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Docker file probably doesn't matter, but is here: https://github.com/neuropower/neuropower-web/blob/development/neuropower/Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution ! Number of threads in the uwsgi.ini was only 1.  Increasing this solved the problem.

**uwsgi.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
master = true
processes = 4
threads = 4 
socket = :3031
chdir = /code/
post-buffering = true
log-date = true
max-requests = 5000
wsgi-file = neuropowertools/wsgi.py
```